# execute script from within python3 interpreter and show interpreter results

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, interpreter

I am working inside the python 3 interpreter, and I want to use it for homework.

first, I have a library called `mylibrary.py` like this

```
from math import pi
def area_circle(r):
   return(r*r*pi))
```

Second, I have a script called `homework.py` like this

```
from mylibrary import *
area_circle(3)
area_circle(5)
area_circle(3) + area_circle(5)
```

Now, I want to enter the python interpreter and somehow execute the script `homework.py` as if I had typed these lines directly into the interpreter, and I want the results to appear on the screen as the interpreter normally displays them.

from the BASH prompt:

```
$python3

Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> exec "homework"
```

Is there such a command?  I want it to read my script and enter the lines into the interpreter, so that what appears on the screen next is:

```
>>> from mylibrary import * 
>>> area_circle(3)
28.274333882308138
>>> area_circle(5)
78.53981633974483
>>> area_circle(3) + area_circle(5)
106.81415022205297
```

Please note that I do not have `Idle`, i do not have `iPython`, I just have the interpreter which I access from the BASH prompt.

I know that I could replace the functions in the library to explicitly call the print function, something like this:

```
def area_circle(r):
   a=r*r*pi
   print(a)
   return()
```

But I don't want that, as it would prevent me from using this function as a building block of future functions.
So I guess what I'm asking is how to execute the `homework` script line by line into the interpreter, in the simplest way possible.

Comment: You can run `homework.py` from bash, by passing the filename to the interpreter : `python3 homework.py`.

Comment: this answer does not output any results

Comment: If you want to go into interactive python after running your code, you can use the `-i` option:  `python3 -i homework.py`.  It runs your code, then gives the `>>>` prompt so you can interrogate variables.

Comment: this would only work if I went to the trouble of storing each result in a separate variable, and it also doesn't print out the commands within the script.  For the homework I want the command and its resultant output to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can"t show the content without using 'print' if you're not using python prompt ....

You can modify your function, so it prints if a second argument is given, and doesn't print otherwise :

```
def area_circle(r, do_print=False):
    a=r*r*pi
    if do_print:
        print(a)
    return a
```

This function will return the area in all the case. It will also print its value if you give it `True` as a second argument (`area_circle(3)` prints nothing and returns the area, while `area_circle(3,True)` print the area, and also returns its value)